# how to free NSMutableString safely in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablestring

```
-(void)showLog
{
    NSMutableString* msgStr = nil;

    msgStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%s","Log :"];

    //show Log

    [msgStr release];

}
```

This is my code. I call this function from a thread frequently. I have disabled ARC and I am testing on iPad Mini with iOS 7 from xcode 5. in XCode 5, its show successive memory allocation. Even though I release this `msgStr` why does it shows increment in memory allocation?

Any help or suggestion will be great.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "its show successive memory allocation".

Comment: You are overreleasing the string. I don't think you're understanding the memory situation correctly.

Comment: I have a while loop in my thread. On each iteration I call this methods. and each time it shows higher count for memory allocated by my application.

Comment: @Chuck, I have tested also without `[msgStr release]`. It was my old implementation. without releasing it was showing the same behavior

Comment: You should read Apple's memory guides. You don't release the object that you don't own. In your case, you don't own the object. Generally speaking, you don't own the strings most of time.

Comment: Just so you know when moving to `xcode 5.1 IDE` this doesn't support OSX Garbage collection, and attempting to build such targets will result in a build error. Apple recommend that you use the migration tools to convert to ARC (http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_5.1_beta_4_hte6yx/xcode_5.1__beta_4_release_notes.pdf)

Comment: That string is only a few bytes long. How are you even noticing any memory growth?

Comment: @Chuck I'm betting this is a cut down version of what they are really doing.

Comment: If I replace `msgStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%s","Log :"];` with `msgStr = @"Log :";` and convert datatype to `NSString` then memory remains in control. it does not grow.

Comment: This method on its own in the context of a normal Cocoa (Touch) project will not cause unbounded memory growth. Something else you are doing has to be the issue. So again: **How are you seeing memory growth with a six-character string?** Are you calling this in a long loop or what?

Comment: @Chuck Yes. I have a loop in a thread from which this method is being called 1000s of times. hence I can observe it.

Answer (score 5):

the point you missing here

```
[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_someString];
```

This line create a autorelease nsstring object, because  `stringWithFormat` is a factory method which return a instance variable of type nsstring.

In second line you are releasing it. no need to do this here, it will be released from autorelease pool.

Comment: I was not releasing that string in my old code, but it is not being freed so, i tried with manually release. Though it shows increment in total memory allocated by application. I am not using instrument, but observ FPS, Memory and CPU from xcode 5's left side pannel

Comment: `stringWithFormat:` called from `NSMutableString` will create a `NSMutableString`. Nothing wrong with that part.

Comment: @sam18 your string will get released when autorelease pool will be drain. so you dont need to worry about its memory allocation.

Answer (score 2):

`stringWithFormat:` returns an autoreleased `NSString`, so you are overreleasing it. It is not leaking. Memory allocations will happen all the time and are only a problem if not released anymore or if leaking.

How do you check for memory allocations? Are you using Instruments?

Comment: Initially I was using `stringWithFormat` it was showing increment in memory allocation without memory leak. XCode 5 shows FPS, Memory and CPU usage in side panel while running application on device.

Comment: Without the full code it is not possible to determine if the increase in allocated memory is to be expected or not. There are various reasons memory alloc will raise over time, for example if you are displaying the log text in a view and just append new log entries at the end. That must increase allocations.

Comment: The scope of this variable is within this function only. I am not passing this variable to any function.

Comment: `stringWithFormat:` called from `NSMutableString` will create a `NSMutableString`. Nothing wrong with that part.

Comment: @Desdenova it is not about mutability of strings but about memory persistence. stringWithFormat: is autoreleased.

Comment: @Desdenova : Can this be a problem with iOS 7 OR XCode 5? because if I am not calling this function then XCode 5's allocated memory count does not grow.

Comment: @sam18 it is not iOS7 or Xcode 5 problem, but without more details no one can help you. The increase in memory alloc may be normal even.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to self release your `NSString` instance, do it like this:

```
-(void)showLog
{
    NSMutableString* msgStr = nil;

    msgStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", "Log :"];

    //show Log

    [msgStr release];
}
```

If you don't change `msgStr` use an immutable string type:

```
-(void)showLog
{
    NSString* msgStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", "Log :"];

    //show Log

    [msgStr release];
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do the `alloc init` on `NSString`s anymore.

Comment: @Popeye the questioner disabled ARC, so if an autorelease pool shouldn't be used, there's no way around alloc/init...

Comment: @Popeye: What do you mean by "you don't need alloc/init NSString"? - Of course it can make sense to alloc/init an object and release it explicitly for better control of the lifetime  instead of an autoreleased object.

Comment: I will have a look when I'm not so busy but Apple have stated that you know long have to do `alloc init` on an `NSString` you can just do `NSString *myStr = @"hello world";` I will look for the documentation that Apple released for it.